# How to create a case class given a schema

Tags: scala, schema, case-class

I am trying to create a case class given the schema of another case class, so that given:

```
case class givenClass(given1: Type1, given2:Type1)
```

I could create a new case class:

```
case class newClass(given1:Type1, given2:Type2, new3:Type3...)
```

One direction I have tried to follow is inferring the schema of givenClass using Scala Reflection and then creating a new case class given that schema, but I am having trouble finding a good way to do it.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? There may well be better ways of dealing with the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Seems like you for this issue you can use an abstract class.

Comment: which [type of] schema do you have?

Comment: @Tim Yeah I have a pipeline that transforms datasets, and for consistency I want a transformation on a dataset to output a schema that includes the fields of the original dataset. For example if the original dataset is Original(name:String, age:Int), and one of the transformations is to add a height column, I would like the result to be Result(name:String, age:Int, height:Double). But, if the schema of the original table changes to include also weight, for example, I would like that change to be propagated to the rest of the case classes without having to change it

Comment: The problem you have is that a `case classe` is defined at compile time so you are not going to be able to use this class even if you could create it. But if you just want to add a `height` field then create a wrapper class `case class newClass[T](given: T, new3: Type3)`